# How to set Autolayout constrains with Visual format in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to use autolayout with visual format in swift 3 and it keeps crashing. The code below basically adds a few UIImageView to a scroll view and make it scrollable.
However, when i tried to add constraints to the scroll view and the imageview, the app keep crashing, code works fine on swift 2.3

```
let page1 = createAndAddViewsWith("image1", middleTextLabel: "Welcome to TwisCode")
    let page2 = createAndAddViewsWith("image2", middleTextLabel: "This is just a practice")
    let page3 = createAndAddViewsWith("image3", middleTextLabel: "And the button will appear here")


    pages = [page1, page2, page3]

    print(pages)

    let views = ["view": view, "page1": page1.view, "page2": page2.view, "page3": page3.view]
    let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[p1.view(==view)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalConstraints)
```

So the part where i added vertical constraints is the part where it crashes.

Below is the function to add pages.

```
private func createAndAddViewsWith (_ backgroundImage: String, middleTextLabel text: String )-> ContentViewController{

    let contentVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
    contentVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentVC.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: backgroundImage)
    contentVC.textLabel = text

    scrollView.addSubview(contentVC.view)
    addChildViewController(contentVC)
    contentVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    return contentVC


}
```

Comment: What type of crash is happening? Does it point you to some line in code? Is it related to explicit unwrapping? Is it auto layout warning? Provide some more info.

Comment: i put break point to the code above and it crashes on the verticalConstraints
The error was "NSInvalidArgumentException" - unrecognized selector sent to instance nslayoutconstraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the issue is caused by the type of the views array. In my case:

```
var nibview: UIView!
// ...
let views = ["nib": nibView]   // Type: [String: UIView?]
```

Casting it to ensure the values are not optional seems to fix it (The bottom one casts it to what constraints.withVisualFormat expects).

```
let views: [String: UIView] = ["nib": nibView]
let views: [String: Any] = ["nib": nibView]
```

Alternately, you could just make sure your views array never has an optional view. (I had to explicitly unwrap an implicitly unwrapped optional, which I found odd).

```
let views = ["nib": nibView!]
```

This post is where I learned the cause:
[Autolayout issue Xcode 8 [_SwiftValue nsli_superitem]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520534/autolayout-issue-xcode-8-swiftvalue-nsli-superitem)