# Autolayout issue Xcode 8 [_SwiftValue nsli_superitem]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Converting my code to Swift 3 I found a weird issue.
Right now (15th September 2016) Xcode 8 (public version) is out, and after converting the code, my App crashes without an apparently reason.

There is something wrong with Auto Layout and the log says something like:

```
[_SwiftValue nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

How can I solve? Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just figured out the weird but working solution:

Instead of doing this:

```
let views = ["view":aView]
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "...", options:[], metrics: metrics, views: views))
```

Declare the dictionary explicitly:

```
let views: [String:UIView] = ["view":aView]
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "...", options:[], metrics: metrics, views: views))
```

I know, it's weird but it works.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. For me it was unwrapping the view, which was an optional. So `let views = ["view":aView!]`

Comment: At least yours converted.  My project upgrade just completely ignores all of my constraints.  Reverted the changes and retried 3 times in a row.  My client is just going to love me having to completely redo their entire interface prior to getting to the small features they wanted updated.

Comment: Thanks @martn_st, that's what worked for me.  My declaration is `@IBOutlet weak var aTableView: UITableView!`, which I thought meant that it was already unwrapped.  I guess in Swift 3, it's not enough?

Comment: Here is the explanation: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md

Comment: It would've taken me forever to figure this out. Thanks for asking & answering.

Comment: You are my savior 

Comment: It worked for me too, but what happens if I want to create a constraint to `topLayoutGuide` using visual format? Typing to UIView throws an error :(

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3, the way we work with implicitly unwrapped optionals has changed. Consider the following example:

```
let optionalInt: Int! = 1
let int = optionalInt
let array = [int, 2]
print(array) // prints: [Optional(1), Optional(2)]
```

So instead of having an array of type `[Int]` as expected, we now have `[Int?]`, which causes the above runtime error.

---

**pascalbros**'s workaround to explicitly declare the type of the variable solves the issue, but to be sure what happens there, I'd recommend to check the possible optionals unexpectedly getting into an array or dictionary and changing its inferred type.